# Error Installing Emulator In Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm not able to install Emulator in my laptop. It's showing an error, could someone suggest what should I do ? I've attached the error screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Did you check the installation log as the image says?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **HAXM** from the **SDK Manager** and go the root directory and install the HAXM and then you are good to go!!

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the virtualization technology is not enabled for your device.It can be solved by enabling it.
 (For a windows based device)Go to

`Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn windows feature on or off->Hyper-V`

Check this option and reinstall.
If this option is not present in your computer then try doing from boot-menu:

```
1.)  Press F10 (Computer Boot Up)->BIOS->Security->System Security-> Virtual Technology (VTX)
     Enable
     Save and Exit
2.)Goto sdk Folder:    
     F:\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager 
     Run intelhaxm-android.exe
```

You will see a  dialog box which says, "Completed Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager Set Up Wizard. Click the Finish Button to exit the wizard"
Once this works, open android studio, and try running the emulator.